# Kerberized NFSv4 no write permission

Tags: permissions, root, disk, nfs, kerberos

I have some trouble with installing NFSv4 with Kerberos. I can't write on my NFSv4-Share.

That's my `/etc/exports`:

```
/srv/export/      gss/krb5p(rw,fsid=0,no_subtree_check,async,no_root_squash)
```

Thats my `/srv/exports`:

```
root@server:/srv/export# ls -lah   insgesamt 20K     drwxr-xr-x  4
root root 4,0K Sep 12 13:58 .   drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4,0K Sep 12
13:58 ..   -rw-r--r--  1 root root   50 Sep 11 05:12 geheimnis  
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root 4,0K Sep 12 17:45 home   drwxr-xr-x  3 root
root 4,0K Sep 11 11:57 mnt
```

That’s my `/srv/exports/home`:

```
root@server:/srv/export/home# ls -la   drwxr-xr-x 11 root  root 4096
Sep 12 17:45 .   drwxr-xr-x  4 root  root 4096 Sep 12 13:58 ..  
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root    4 Sep 12 13:45 ccccccccc.txt   drwxr-xr-x  2 user1 users 4096 Sep 12 14:28 user1   -rwxr-xr-x  1 root  root   13
Sep 12 14:27 do.sh   drwxr-xr-x  2 user2   users 4096 Sep 11 05:33
user2   drwxr-xr-x  2 user3   users 4096 Sep 12 14:21 user3  
drwxr-xr-x  2 user4  users 4096 Sep 11 05:34 user4   drwxr-xr-x  2
user5 users 4096 Sep 12 13:44 user5
```

As you can see the User-Permissions are fine.

I tried the following mount command:

```
mount -v -t nfs4 -o sec=krb5p SERVER:/home /home
```

This works fine. But when I try to write on my NFS-Share with Root-Permissions I get an:

```
Permission Denied
```

I tried also the following:

Add new user principal. Then execute kinit with the user, then I can read the NFS-Share as Non-Root User but I still can't write on it.

Any Idea how I can solve this Problem?